# Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient (Ubuntu)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, bigdata

I have successfully installed Java, Hadoop MySQL. I am getting this error while running hive. I was getting the file permission error before which got fixed by making the metastore_db folder under hive folder to 777 permission mode. How can i resolve this issue.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:565)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 28 more
```

I tried even moving the db.lck and dbex.lck files It did not work. I restarted Hadoop and machine several times after the changes made nothing worked. Help !
Thanks in advance.

hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>     <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
      <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>    </property>

   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
      <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>    </property>

   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>root</value>
      <description>USER NAME</description>    </property>

   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>root</value>
      <description>PASSWORD ***</description>    </property>  </configuration>
```

Comment: can you update your question with `hive-site.xml`

Comment: I have added the sitemap please ignore the formatting.

Comment: Is it named `hive-sitemap.xml`? If yes, rename it to `hive-site.xml`. Hive is not recognizing these properties and thus starting hive metastore in embedded mode with `derby`.

Comment: I am sorry, it is hive-site.xml. FYI As per the property it creates the metastore db in the mysql server which confirms the db connectivity.

Comment: But in the post you have mentioned about the folder `metastore_db`. It is created only if the hive runs its metastore in embedded mode

Comment: Initially metastore_db folder had permission issues, which got fixed by changing the permission. Now embedded mode ? I am unfamiliar with it

Comment: `metastore_db` does not come into picture if hive is using MySQL for metastore.

Comment: Now i get it, hive-site.xml file was not present earlier then i had to work with metastore_db then i configured hive-site.xml with mysql since then I am getting this error.

Comment: That said it, since `hive-site.xml` wasn't there. Hive ran in embedded mode with derby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the property, it will create only the database but not the schema. Try creating the schema required for Hive metastore in MySQL

```
 cd $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/
 < login to mysql >
 mysql> use metastore;
 mysql> source hive-schema-<your_version>.mysql.sql;
```

Then restart hive metastore process.

Comment: But i have never started metastore process, how do I do it?

Comment: If using to MySQL, you have to start it separately. `hive --service metastore`, you can run this process in background, `nohup hive --service metastore &`

Comment: After loading the hive schema I've started metastore service, its up and running (I could no further use that terminal, This is how this server is running i suppose)
then i tried hive command am getting another error trace, this time hadoop refused its connection 


Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:

Comment: If you had started it as background process, you can use the same terminal.. for the new errors, is your namenode configured to run in 9000 port? If yes check whether it is running.

Comment: Namenode is not configured to run on 9000, i assume it needs some exception some where. the port 9000 is free to use more help on this

Comment: When a hive query is executed, hive tries to access its warehouse in HDFS. Is your namenode process running? What is the value of property `fs.defaultFS` or `fs.default.name` in `core-site.xml`?

Comment: sir, i have my core-site.xml pasted with the question. The other way, can you provide the proper core-site.xml properties? I will use them, i am quite unsure to add others. Beginner though

Comment: You have pasted `hive-site.xml`, `core-site.xml` will be inside the hadoop folder. Please post the property inside core-site.xml to debug. Also    add the output of command `jps`

Comment: jps

2735 SecondaryNameNode

2553 DataNode

7096 Jps

5423 RunJar

3020 NodeManager

2891 ResourceManager

Comment: core-site.xml
<configuration>
<property>        
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>        
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>   
 </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Your namenode is configured to run in port 9000 but it is not running, fix that. Hive will work.

Comment: Should I add the port in firewall exception ?

Comment: This should be a simple problem, check your namenode logs.

Comment: Is this error of any sort-able ?  

Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.

Comment: I am not sure of this exception but the port number 9000 could be a reason. Try, remove the port number from `fs.defaultFS`, the value should look like `hdfs://localhost/`. Restart hadoop then.

Comment: My hdfs-site has only this 

<configuration>
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 2):

For me, I got this error when not start hive inside $HIVE_HOME.